# capacitor push-notifications OR firebase messaging service worker

Tags: angular, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am confused as to which packages should I implement in my Angular 14 Ionic 6 Capacitor 4 app, for sending and receiving notifications between app users.
I need to be able to handle incoming messages:

- When app is in background - **display** a tappable notification (pushing to the notifications tray is not enough!) that will bring the app to foreground and further route based on received data payload.
- When app is in foreground - process logic based on data payload received.

My initial approach was to implement with *@capacitor/push-notifications*, with the two listeners implemented:

```
pushNotificationReceived

pushNotificationActionPerformed
```

However, I found the following shortcomings with that approach:

1. In background - messages are only delivered to the notifications tray - not popping up.
2. In background, un-tapped notifications will never be processed by the app leading to important data that must mutate the application state - to be lost!
3. In foreground, the much needed baloon popup notifications *in background* - are now shown (when not really needed to be shown).

Then I encountered the [firebase/messaging service worker][1] approach.

I have not yet implemented it at all, but it seems to me, that while offers the `onBackgroundMessage` method to capture and handle background notifications, to fall short on:

1. Not leveraging the native notification service offered by Android/iOS
2. Not showing any popup notification, unless I implement it myself(?)

At this point I'm somewhat confused:

1. Is it possible that my requirements can only be met by using BOTH approaches and packages?
2. Is it at all possible to implement both? (in which case, the same token I register upon the 'registration' listener registration in initPush(), will serve BOTH?)
3. If one approach is enough - which is it, and how to overcome what seems to me missing, in order to fulfill my requirements?

Thank you!
[1]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive

Comment: did you have solution with your problem? @Mor Sagmon